# How to disable a page item without removing it from session state

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I have 3 radio groups on my page. When user selects a value in the first radio group, if it is a particular value, the selection in the other two radio groups gets reset to default and they get disabled to prevent changing them.

The issue is that built-in apex `Disable` action uses `disable` javascript property so the value of the radio groups gets removed from session. It would need to use javascript equivalent to `readonly`, which, as far a s I know, does not currently exist in apex.

How can I get around this issue to enable/disable the radio groups based on a selection in another radio group while still being able to access selected value from my code?

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is that readonly doesn't apply to radio buttons, as per the spec. Here's a solution that should work for you but be sure to test in multiple browsers...

1. Add this function to the Function and Global Variable Declaration attribute of the page:

   ```
   function preventRadioSelection(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(this).blur();
   }
   ```
2. Add this CSS to the Inline attribute of the page:

   ```
   .sudo-disabled+label {
     opacity: .5;
     cursor: default;
     pointer-events: none;
   }
   ```
3. When you need to Disable an item, use the Execute JavaScript action with the following code:

   ```
   $(this.affectedElements).find('input').on('click', preventRadioSelection).addClass('sudo-disabled');
   ```

   Then set Affected Elements to the item(s) you want to disable.
4. When you need to Enable an item, use the Execute JavaScript action with the following code:

   ```
   $(this.affectedElements).find('input').off('click', preventRadioSelection).removeClass('sudo-disabled');
   ```

   Then set Affected Elements to the item(s) you want to enable.

Keep in mind that all of this is client-side, and could be worked around by someone that knows what they're doing. You'll need to enforce your business rules with server-side validations.